# Pyautogui Returns a Screenshot That Crashes My Script

Tags: python, ui-automation, pyautogui

I am trying to use pyautogui to gather screenshots inside of a while loop to mimic that of a video feed of my computer screen. My problem is that sometimes this script works pperfectly, other times the pyautogui.screenshot() returns a grey opencv image that ends up crashing the program.

```
# Manually enter the four points of the bounded box (x, y) coordinates
points = [
    (100, 50),  # Top-left corner
    (500, 50),  # Top-right corner
    (2500, 1400),  # Bottom-right corner
    (100, 400)   # Bottom-left corner
]

scaling_factor = 0.5
while True:
    time.sleep(.2)
    threshold = 2300
    frame = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(points[0][0], points[0][1], points[2][0] - points[0][0], points[2][1] - points[0][1]))
    frame1 = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(frame), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    IsSearching = find_image_match_in_rectangle(frame1, template_image_path, rectangle_top_left, rectangle_width, rectangle_height)
    if (Lockin)==True:
        #reset the filter
        print("NO SNIPES to reset")
    if (IsSearching) == True:
        Lockin = False
        print("Searching")
    if (IsSearching)== False:
        GetValues = draw_rectangles(frame1, num_rectangles, initial_top_left, rectangle_size, x_shift)
        if (GetValues[1])<threshold:
            print("Buy pos 1 at {}".format(GetValues[1]))
            buy1()
        if (GetValues[2])<threshold:
            print("Buy pos 2 at {}".format(GetValues[2]))
            #buy2()
        if (GetValues[3])<threshold:
            print("Buy pos 3 at {}".format(GetValues[3]))
            #buy3()
        if (GetValues[4])<threshold:
            print("Buy pos 4 at {}".format(GetValues[4]))
            #buy4()
        if (GetValues[5])<threshold:
            print("Buy pos 5 at {}".format(GetValues[5]))
            #buy5()
        if (GetValues[6])<threshold:
            print("Buy pos 6 at {}".format(GetValues[6]))
            #buy6()
        Lockin = True
        continue
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(25)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

I have no idea why it works sometimes, and other times it does not.

Comment: welcome. [mre] required. there is still a bunch of stuff in your code that is beside the issue. also your code contains waitKey but no imshow. the waitKey is pointless then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you might faced is because infinite screenshot from pyautogui, which might lead to crash.
Instead using pyautogui use opencv prebuilt frame capturing function `cv2.VideoCapture(camera number)`

If you want to capture application use OBS to capture screen and set it to virtual camera and set the videocapture number to 1  `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` or other

the below code reads frame by frame and captures specific area as you coded before

```
import cv2

# Bounded box coordinates
top_left = (100, 50)
bottom_right = (2500, 1400)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Capture the screen within the bounded box
while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = frame[top_left[1]:bottom_right[1], top_left[0]:bottom_right[0]]

    # Process the captured frame here
    # ...

    cv2.imshow("Captured Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(25)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

hope it helps to you.

Comment: Awesome, I will try this when I get home today. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome. good luck with your project

Comment: explanation is wrong. pyautogui.screenshot should have no trouble. there is no issue with "infinite". "might" is hedging your bets. this answer fails to identify the problem.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, sorry if I'm wrong but the code (Or method)I gave works more efficient

Comment: no it's not and you don't even support your claim. it's actually LESS efficient because you involve OBS, which captures the screen, puts the data into a "virtual camera" device, which then has to be read by opencv. all of this will involve not just copying of data but also transformations. direct screen capture using pyautogui (and whatever system APIs it uses) is more efficient.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz What would your solution be to fix the pyautogui then?

Comment: first, this question needs a [mre]. there's an undefined identifier, for one. once this is reproducible, it can be debugged. if this can't be made reproducible, the best you can hope for is suggestions for _other_ solutions (as this answer provides), without ever finding out what actually went wrong with whatever you did. your code, except for the obvious issues, should be working. pyautogui isn't generally so broken as to cause the issue you describe. it's simply not reproducible.